# enable MANY class's member fields at once, depending on template <T>

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, enable-if

Here is [MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7da8c41650c6512).  It works :-

```
template<bool c3> class Has3 { };
template<> class Has3<true> { public: int cat3; };

template<bool c2,bool c3> class Has2 : public Has3<c3>{ };
template<bool c3> struct Has2<true,c3> : public Has3<c3>{ public: int dog2; };

template<bool c1,bool c2,bool c3> class Has1 : public Has2<c2,c3>{ };
template<bool c2,bool c3> struct Has1<true,c2,c3> : 
     public Has2<c2,c3>{public:  int rat1; }; //<- ugly, in my opinion.

int main(){
    Has1<false,true,false> h; 
    h.dog2=5;
    //h.cat3=4;  //<- compile error (which is good)
}
```

The above inelegant MCVE is modified from  [enable class's member depending on template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930916/enable-classs-member-depending-on-template), which can enable only one field at a time.
(I read both answers, but its second solution uses too much memory.)

How to toggle many fields on/off easily?
It is sad that this MCVE becomes a mess pretty fast.

In my real cases, I have about 5-6 unique fields, that are different types.
For simplicity, the type of `cat3`,`dog2`,... does not depend on T.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have something simpler with:

```
class Cat  { public: int cat3; };
struct Dog { public: int dog2; };
struct Rat { public: int rat1; };

template <typename... Bases>
class Group : public Bases... {};
```

And then

```
Group<Dog, Rat> h;

h.dog2=5;
```

Comment: Ha! I can't stop laughing.   Good answer.  I will see whether I can use in my real case.  Thanks!

Comment: In your answer, what is the best way to query e.g. whether a `T` e.g. `T=Group<Dog,Rat>` has `Dog` (or `dog2`) at compile time?  I lose the ability to query that info easily.

Comment: @cppBeginner: You might use `std::is_base_of<Dog, MyGroup>`.